# QUnit - Basic test - check field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am very new to QUnit. Picked a simple JavaScript function to write a qunit test against it. Here is the function:

```
function createSelectField(parent, elemid, value, collection) {
 var elem1 = document.createElement("select");
 elem1.id = elemid; 
      parent.appendChild(elem1);
 $("#" +  elemid).addOption(collection, false);
 if(value != null) {
         elem1.value = value ;
 }
 var oldvalue = value;
}
```

It creates a select field, appends it to a parent, adds some options to it (using a JQuery plug in) and sets the default value to whatever is passed in. I am trying to write two tests for this function, one when value is null, and one when value is some string. The assumption of the test  it to check the value of the field.

Here is what I tried:

```
module('Test createSelectField');
test('createSelectField() with no default value', function() {   
var parent = document.createElement("div");
createSelectField(parent, 'umbi', null, {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"});
var elem = $('#umbi');
equal(elem.val(), null, "No default value provided for the drop down");

}); 

test('createSelectField() with some default value', function() {   
var parent = document.createElement("div");
createSelectField(parent, 'bi', 'key1', {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"});
var elem = $('#bi');
equal(elem.val(), 'key1', "Default to key1 value");

});
```

First of all, I tried to get the element created using document.getElementById, that didn't work, it returned null. Using JQuery selector seems to get me the element, but I do not see the value (debugged with FireBug) (I am not even sure it gives me the element that I created inside my function). I even tried to return the element from my main function, but still not working. I am confused and fustrated. I'd like to write unit testing my my javascript, but this almost makes me want to give up. Help?!

Answer (score 1):

Because your elements are not inserted in the page but inside the the div you created the CSS query `$('#umbi')` can not work as it would look inside the document.

Where `$('#umbi', parent)` will search for it in the parent context and will work even if the element is not part of the DOM.

But as for your test you only insert a single item you could also access it via `div.childNodes[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that got me a few steps forward. Now the remaining issue I have, when I pass in a value like 'key1', it goes into the if block in my function, looks like it is setting the value on the elem, but when I debug in FireBug, the value is still "", and it is what I am getting in my test too.

Comment: I suspect the value assignment in your function is wrong. You create a select element, which never have a value (jQuery $(select).val() make it sound like there is), instead it's the option that contains the value, the select can only provide you with the selectedIndex. So really what you want to assign for the default option to be selected is the elem1.selectedIndex (this is an array key however and the options are passed as an object in your case)

Comment: I see. Actually, now that you mentioned, I also noticed in debug mode that `$("#" + elemid).addOption(collection, false); `is not adding my collection to the list of the select options. (now, I should say that this code I tested it from the UI, and it is working fine, for me writting the test cases is more educational). So I think I might have some other issue with the custom plug in when executed from the test script. Anyway, I will keep trying. Thank you again.